# How to install java jdk in RHEL?

Tags: linux, java, redhat

I am following example commands from other sites but it isn't helping!

What am I doing wrong?

```
chmod +x jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin
./jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

Results give me:

```
bash: ./jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Ok.. after doing

```
sh jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

as suggested below, I get this:

[image]

Did the install fail?  Is the file corrupted??? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try it to run as normal user or as root?

Comment: I first was root, but the file was in my /media folder so I went into there... was it because the file was not in the root directory?

Comment: Hmm. maybe your user doesn't have read permission to file, but has exec permission? Do ls -l jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin and if file cannot be read by others, then do chmod o+r jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin. Anyway, I think that JDK should be installed by root in the systemwide directory.

Comment: Ah.. ok I think I fixed it by putting the jdk bin file in root instead of leaving it in the /media folder.  Is it suggested to install all programs in the root folder?

Comment: No, your rpm file can be anywhere.

Comment: It seems that unpacked file ./install.sfx.20555 is not executable. Does your partition mounted with "exec" option? Also, do you have 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: I am not sure about the "exec" option and how I can check.. I have a 32 bit system.

Comment: ok, show output of command "mount | grep noexec". Also, you can download plain binary from Oracle site and try it.

Comment: Output of command "mount | grep noexec" is /dev/sdb1 on /media/1C type vfat (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,shortname=winnt,uid=0)

Comment: uthark, I think the java jdk install is fine.. everything went ok after I moved the install bin file to the root directory.  Not sure what happened when it was in the /media folder though...

Comment: Heh. As you can see, you /media/1C is mounted as noexec. So, any files that are placed on that drive cannot be executed, that is why installation failed until you moved it to the /root directory, which, I assume is mounted with exec option.

Comment: oooohh... cool beans.  Thanks for all your help uthark! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to run it using sh itself, i.e

```
sh jdk-6u24-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are doing correct.

To install the Linux RPM (self-extracting) file
Follow these instructions:

1. Become the root user by running the su command and entering the super-user password.
     At the terminal: Type:

   ```
   su
   ```

   Enter the root password.
2. Change to the directory in which you want to install. Type:

   ```
   cd <directory>
   ```

   For example, to install the software in the /usr/java/ directory, Type:

   ```
   cd /usr/java
   ```

   Note about root access: To install Java in a system-wide location such as/usr/local, you must login as the root user to gain the necessary permissions. If you do not have root access, install Java in your home directory or a subdirectory for which you have write permissions.
3. Change the permission of the file you downloaded to be executable. Type:

   ```
   chmod a+x jre-6u<version>-linux-i586-rpm.bin
   ```
4. Start the installation process. Type:

   ```
   ./jre-6u<version>-linux-i586-rpm.bin
   ```

   The license agreement is displayed. Review the agreement. Press the spacebar to display the next page. At the end, enter yes to proceed with the installation.
5. The installation file creates and runs the file jre-6-linux-i586.rpm in the current directory.

   RPM unpacking completes
6. Verify that the jre1.6.0_ sub-directory is listed under the current directory. Type:

   ```
   ls
   ```

   Verify the installation filename

Also refer: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#rpm